# bootstrap multiple modal structure

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, frontend

I have a structure as below. Modal1 for displaying my content and Modal2 pops up when a alert modal when deleting.

1. I have first modal1 loading in Ajax
2. Second modal is not Ajax call.
3. Is it advisable to have this structure with multiple modals? Otherwise what is the alternative to get alert message in a modal?
   Because right now I am facing weird issues with closing modals and events. It is working some times and some time it doesn't . Not sure what causes the weirdness. 
   Any leads on do and don'ts will be helpful. 
   https://plnkr.co/edit/ZaUfPntbVp3QMubaw8xg?p=preview

   ```
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" 
   data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
   <div class="modal-content">
     <div class="modal-header">
     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
     <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-body">
     <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2">Open Modal</button>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-footer">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
   </div>
   ```

```
  <!-- Modal content-->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">Alert : Are you sure?</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Nested modals are not supported in bootstrap 3 that's why you are getting wired results

From bootstrap [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#modals):

> Multiple open modals not supported
>   Be sure not to open a modal while another is still visible. Showing more than one modal at a time requires custom code.

Instead of using a second modal You can use an [alert](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#alerts) to show notification msg inside the first modal

Comment: But I want the alert message to be displayed like a modal with backdrop. My requirement is in inside modal1 if I delete a content I want another modal with with alert message https://plnkr.co/edit/ZaUfPntbVp3QMubaw8xg?p=preview.